# Using XOR on characters as a simple checksum; is a char just a byte?

Tags: arduino-c++

I have a string of characters and want to generate a simple checksum by accumulating XOR on each character, then adding the lowest-order byte result of that to the end of the string as formatted by `sprintf(twoCharacterBuffer, "%02X", valueHoldingXOR);`.

If I just XOR the characters in the string, putting them into an `unsigned char` value, the compiler warns me that "'sprintf' output between 3 and 9 bytes into a destination of size 2"

The Arduino documentation is a little vague, possibly on purpose, about the number of bytes in a character. I'd like to just XOR the lowest-order byte, whether it's 1 or 2 or 4 bytes, but am not sure of the correct way to do that. Or can I assume that a `char` is a `byte` and just cast it?

Comment: "A character equals a byte" is only true for obsolete character codes such as ASCII.   But even for ASCII, you can't sprintf two characters into a two-byte buffer, since you need a byte for the null terminator.

Comment: How is `twoCharacterBuffer` declared? As mentioned in the previous comment, if it is `char twoCharacterBuffer[2]`, it is too small to hold 2 chars and a null byte.